# How Do I identify the Docker Containers That Are Managed by PREvant

Tags: docker, prevant

I'm using [PREvant](https://github.com/aixigo/PREvant) with the Docker backend to review development versions of my microservice application. However, I want to execute some commands inside of a specific Docker container. How can I identify the containers of a certain application with `docker ps`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PREvant adds labels to all containers when they will be created. The labels include, e.g. the service name and the application name. With following command you can identify the container ID and the service name in one line (replace `my-application` with your application name):

```sh
docker ps \
  --filter "label=com.aixigo.preview.servant.app-name=my-application" \
  --format '{{.ID}} {{.Label "com.aixigo.preview.servant.service-name"}}'
```

If you have a Kafka container in your application you can open a shell inside of the container with following command:

```sh
docker exec -it \
  $(docker ps --filter "label=com.aixigo.preview.servant.app-name=my-application" --filter "label=com.aixigo.preview.servant.service-name=kafka" -q) \
  sh
```